# how to execute data through label.Text in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm new in vb.net. I'm using vb.net and sql

I had query this "SELECT * FROM sf_OEEShowRed" and how I'm going to show the result in Label1.Text? Below are my code.

```
Private Function GetRed()
    Try

        Dim connectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("StrConn")
        Dim sqlConnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim queryString As String = "SELECT * FROM sf_OEEShowRed"

        Dim sqlCommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)
        sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0

        Dim dataAdapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
        Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)

        Return dataSet
    Finally

        Label1.Text = 

    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: What do you really want to do? Can you clarify your question? `i had query in label1.text`?

Comment: Or do you have any teamviewer so we can check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
  Me.Label1.Text = dataSet.tables(0).defaultview
```